# ImageView memory leak when start other activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a simple activity named Test1.

This is the layout code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/load"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my `onDestory` method, I release the `mImageView` resource and in Android profile, the memory of `mImageView` has really be recycled.

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseImageViewResource(mImageView);
        layout.removeView(mImageView);
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        mImageView = null;
    }
```

[image]
But when I start other simple activity, the memory of `mImageView` cannot be recycled. Why and how to solve the problem?
[image]

Comment: `But when I start other simple activity`? What does this mean? Do you mean, you started the 1st activity with ImageView and then started another activity from that activity? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: finish that activity where you have written onDestroy or else onDestroy() won't be called,

Answer (score 0):

To handle images, I suggest for you to use libraries like [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), they will handle everything for you. (memory leaks, caching, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "start other simple activity", but if you are going to another activity within the application, then your current activity (with the imageview) should be paused instead of destroyed. Either call finish() when you go to the other activity or just put that onDestroy() code in the onPause() method